# Combine git commits on same line in same file from 2 branches into 1 branch

Tags: git

I am trying to resolve a complex issue with git that is probably most easily explained with a hypothetical situation:

Lets say I have a `master` branch with a single file that contains a single line:

```
x=1
```

The value of `x` is updated in each commit, and the `master` branch tagged according:

```
Tag=v1
x=1

Tag=v2
x=2

Tag=v3
x=3
```

Now, I need to create a retrospective tag at a commit I am pulling in from a `feature` branch I created from the `v1` tag on the `master` branch.

```
Tag=v1.1
x=1.1
```

Such that the history on the `master` branch is:

```
Tag=v1
x=1

Tag=v1.1
x=1.1

Tag=v2
x=2

Tag=v3
x=3
```

From my testing, this doesn't seem to be possible, because operations like `cherry-pick`, `merge` and `rebase` will always fail with a conflict, as git doesn't know which change to the single line has precedence.

Is this possible? The only option I can see is to do a HARD `reset` and re-apply the changes with new commits, which isn't practical in my real world situation.

Comment: Why is this `on hold`? The question was clear, it was answered and the answer accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a tricky one. I was able to rebase successfully without manually resolving conflicts. Note: you will have to move tags so it might not be the best solution.

`git rebase -i -X theirs -k --root`

Select edit on first commit. Insert any edits then `git rebase --continue`

> -i: interactive rebase
>   -X theirs: tells the merge algorithm which version to pick in 3-way merge
>   -k: preserve empty commits
>   --root: May not be necessary in the real environment. In your example you are inserting after first commit

Comment: Seems to be working. Just doing a few tests. I'm not sure what you mean about moving tags?

Comment: In my tests v2.0 and v3.0 pointed to the old commits. I need to move them to the new shas

Comment: Got it. Works great. Thanks.